# How to point multiple subdomains to a single domain instance in PyroCMS Pro?

Tags: pyrocms

I've seen in the 2.0 multisite documentation that this feature was coming, the ability to create domain aliases to allow multiple domains or multiple subdomains to point to a single domain instance in the multi-site. Has this been implemented in PyroCMS Pro 2.2? If so, how do you configure it?

Use case: I use dev, qa and preview subdomains for most domains that I work with. When I load these onto their respective environments, I need to have them point to their particular domain. It would be preferable to do this without running scripts to change the database every time it's loaded in.

e.g.: dev.example.com; qa.example.com; preview.example.com and example.com should all share the same "domain" instance in the PyroCMS Pro Multi-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "Domains" module in the Control Panel which will let you add aliases, if you are using Professional. It was introduced in 2.1.0 so you'll need to upgrade if you are on 2.0.0.